# Django Rest Framework and React Linkedin Social Authentication OAuth2Error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am building web app with Django Rest Framework as backend and React as frontend.

using below libraries

- Django==3.1.5
- djangorestframework==3.12.2
- dj-rest-auth==2.1.3
- django-allauth==0.44.0

I am trying to implement Linkedin authentication but getting bellow error as mentioned

```
OAuth2Error at /api/v1/appname/linkedin/
Error retrieving access token: b'{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}'
```

Backend code in django rest framework

```
class LinkedInLoginView(CustomLoginView):
    """
    LinkedIn login
    """
    adapter_class = LinkedInOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = "CALL_BACK_URL"
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

and frontend code like

```
<LinkedIn
    clientId="CLIENT_ID"
    callback={callbackLinkedIn}
    scope={["r_liteprofile", "r_emailaddress"]}
    text={rendertext()}
    className='ant-btn LinkdinIcon ant-btn-link'
    redirect_uri="CALL_BACK_URL"
    render={renderProps => (
    <Button type="link" className="LinkdinIcon" onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
<LinkdinIcon /></Button>)}
```

and `CALL_BACK_URL` which is already added under redirect urls in linkedin developers.

Frontend api will generated `code` and pass it to backend api and DRF uses `code` and generate `access_token` and call linkedin profile api (internally)

We have Backend running in different domain and frontend is running on different domain.

Can anybody please help me to understand what would be `CALL_BACK_URL` in backend and what would be in frontend ?

If anybody can share some reference links or code would be appreciated.